# OpenTok real-time audio transcription

Tags: opentok, transcription

I am trying to transcribe the audio in an OpenTok session in real-time. The OpenTok API does not not seem to have that feature. Is there any way I can capture the data in some form and push it to another script/ tool that makes the transcription?

The issue is not with transcribing, the issue is in accessing the live audio stream data and using it in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the video/audio stream (MediaStream) with https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#getUserMedia in client SDK.

You can manipulate audio using available API from WebAudio spec.

Publish audio from an audio MediaStreamTrack object. For example, you can use the AudioContext object and the Web Audio API to dynamically generate audio. You can then call createMediaStreamDestination().stream.getAudioTracks()[0]on the AudioContext object to get the audio MediaStreamTrack object to use as the audioSource property of the optionsobject you pass into the OT.initPublisher() method. For a basic example, see the Stereo-Audio sample OpenTok-web-samples repo on GitHub.

This above GitHub example is about injecting your audio stream. However, you can also extract/capture your audio before injecting it. See detail here...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API.